# cp verbose alternative

Tags: cp

I want to list all of the files that are being copied by a cp command but the -v switch doesn't seem to exist on the servers here at work. I'm not sure exactly which OS this is. I think it might be SunOS. How could I find out if that is important?

Thanks

Comment: `uname -a` might tell you what the OS is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use tar piped to tar instead, which may be more featureful, as you can harness the power of tar in addition to being a cross-platform verbosity solution.

```
tar -cvpf . - | (cd destination/directory && tar -xvpf -)
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked great. Helped me find why the files weren't appearing. I was running it from a shell script and the variables were set wrong. Hopefully I haven't left files all over the server from the times I got it wrong...

Comment: Thanks!  Worked for me too, but had to swap the order of the arguments for tar: `tar -cvpf - . | (cd destination/directory && tar -xvpf -)`

Answer (score 0):

You could also try `ditto` (if it's present on your machine). `ditto -V` will print out each filename as it's copied.

Answer (score 0):

One more option is rsync -v.

Answer (score 0):

cat /etc/issue

to get the distro name

---

unison is lovely too if you can get it installed on the server

http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/